# How to create a executable Jar file for the Groovy script developed using Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, groovy, executable-jar

I have developed groovy script to run the Automation Testing using Eclipse IDE. The code generally triggers the Web service based on the input and Validates the responses.

I have exported the jar file by right clicking the project. The jar file is created.

But when I try to run the jar using Command prompt I am facing an error.

Can anyone please help me how to create a executable jar for the Groovy script

Comment: You need to show how you are doing and what error do you get.

Comment: Most likely the generated JAR file is missing a Manifest entry such as `Main-Class`. The procedure being related to IDE specifics you may need to review the options provided by the IDE. Also, Groovy scripts are not runnable on their own, you must package the groovy dependency in the same JAR.